# Azure Connection SSH and RDP

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm using the portal: https://portal.azure.com, and log in with my Azure account.
I made 2 VM one Windows and the other Linux.
But when I want to open them with RDP (win2016) and SSH (linux) with the Key Public/Private made correctly (puttyGen, Putty) I can't run them.
What do I have to understand?

I'm connected on public wireless (SSID MacDonald or SSID Airport), my VM IP are founded with:

```
Get-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig
```

I set a Static IP from the Configuration NetWorking of my VM (Linux and Windows).

But what I can do to resolve this issue that I can't connect to my VM, with RDP or SSH?

Answer (score 0):

I think more info will be needed for someone to be helpful here.

1. first wall, what error message did you get when you try to connect using RDP or SSH?
2. did you allow RDP or SSH port when you create these VMs? These can be checked in VM settings page on the Azure portal. below is a screenshot of my Linux VM, for your reference:
   [image]

**update:**
I'm not allowed to comment at the moment, so I'm posting my response to the additional info here.

if you're able to connect to the VMs using another connection, it means things work as expected on these VMs. Most likely the wireless connection you mentioned blocks outgoing RDP or SSH traffic. check with its admin on that.